# which version of ubuntu runs on my laptop?

Tags: compatibility

Configuration
HP Pavilion g6-2338ee running Windows 8 64 bit
Intel CORE i5 2.6 GHz
RAM- 4GB
HDD- 500GB
Supports Direct X 11
Intel HD Graphics 4000

Answer (score 0):

That should make it : `cat /etc/*-release`

If you also want to know your kernel version : `uname -a`

Answer (score 0):

You can find out about system requirements at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

To quote:

> Ubuntu Desktop Edition
>
> A good "rule of thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista, Windows 7 or x86 OS X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu even if they are lower-spec than described below.
>
> - 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
> - 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or
>     external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
> - VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> - Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> - Internet access is helpful

You machine more than meets these requirements.

Ubuntu 14.04 is the current long term support version.